# Recursion on Integration Approximation Function

Tags: c++, math

I am attempting to approximate integrals using an adaptive Trapezoidal Rule.

I have a coarse integral approximation:

```
//Approximates the integral of f across the interval [a,b]
double coarse_app(double(*f)(double x), double a, double b) {
    return (b - a) * (f(a) + f(b)) / 2.0;
}
```

I have a fine integral approximation:

```
//Approximates the integral of f across the interval [a,b]
double fine_app(double(*f)(double x), double a, double b) {
    double m = (a + b) / 2.0;
    return (b - a) / 4.0 * (f(a) + 2.0 * f(m) + f(b));
}
```

This is made adaptive by summing the approximation across decreasing portions of the given interval until either the recursion level is too high or the coarse and fine approximation are very close to one another:

```
//Adaptively approximates the integral of f across the interval [a,b] with
//    tolerance tol.
double trap(double(*f)(double x), double a, double b, double tol) {
    double q = fine_app(f, a, b);
    double r = coarse_app(f, a, b);
    if ((currentLevel >= minLevel) && (abs(q - r) <= 3.0 * tol)) {
        return q;
    } else if (currentLevel >= maxLevel) {
        return q;
    } else {
        ++currentLevel;
        return (trap(f, a, b / 2.0, tol / 2.0) + trap(f, a + (b / 2.0), b, tol / 2.0));
    }
}
```

If I manually calculate an integral by breaking it up into sections and using fine_app on it, I get a very good approximation.  However, when I use the trap function, which should do this for me, all of my results are far too small.

For example, trap(square, 0, 2.0, 1.0e-2) gives the output 0.0424107, where the square function is defined as x^2.  However, the output should be around 2.667.  This is far worse than doing a single run of fine_app on the entire interval, which gives a value of 3.

Conceptually, I believe I have it implemented correctly, but there is something about C++ recursion which is not doing what I expect it to.

First time programming in C++, so all improvements are welcome.

Comment: Where is currentLevel defined? I see it no where in your code. If it's a global variable, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have currentLevel defined as a global variable.  Thank you for your answer, below.  I will look through it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have currentLevel defined somewhere else. You don't want to do that. You also calculate your midpoints incorrectly.

Take a = 3, b = 5:

```
[a, b / 2.0] = [3, 2.5]
[a + b / 2.0, b] = 2.5, 3]
```

The correct points should be [3, 4] and [4, 5]

The code should look like this:

```
double trap(double(*f)(double x), double a, double b, double tol, int currentLevel) {
    double q = fine_app(f, a, b);
    double r = coarse_app(f, a, b);
    if ((currentLevel >= minLevel) && (abs(q - r) <= 3.0 * tol)) {
        return q;
    } else if (currentLevel >= maxLevel) {
        return q;
    } else {
        ++currentLevel;
        return (trap(f, a, (a + b) / 2.0, tol / 2, currentLevel) + trap(f, (a + b) / 2.0, b, tol / 2, currentLevel));
    }
}
```

You can add a helper function so you don't have to specify currentLevel:

```
 double integrate(double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, double tol)
 {
     return trap(f, a, b, tol, 1);
 }
```

If I call this as `integrate(square, 0, 2, 0.01)` I get the answer of 2.6875, which means you need an even lower tolerance to converge to the correct result of `8/3 = 2.6666...7`. You can check the exact error bound on this by using the error terms for [Simpson's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule).

Comment: I see.  Silly math mistake on calculating the intervals.  Why is it bad to increment a global variable?  It seems it would produce the same effect.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I see that using the helper function such that I do not need currentLevel to be a global variable has helped.  It now converged on the correct value,  However, I do not understand why this helped.

Comment: I now understand why I do not want currentLevel as a global variable.  Having it as a global variable completely defeats the conceptual purpose of the adaptive algorithm.  I need it to be dependent on the current level of the function's recursion.  Thanks.

Comment: @kienjakenobi: Yes, that's exactly the reason why. In more complicated scenarios, if you left this as a global variable it would become even more obvious why this scheme would break. Best of luck with your future C++ programming!